# `power/persist` file not found in USB device sysfs directory

Tags: linux, kernel, usb, usb-drive, kernel-modules

The file [/usr/share/doc/linux-doc/usb/persist.txt.gz](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/usb/persist.txt) mentions that the USB-persist capability can be enabled for a given USB device by writing `1` to the file `persist` in that device's directory in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/$device/power`.  This is said — if I understood correctly — to allow mountings of volumes on the drive to persist across power loss during suspend.

However, I've discovered that the device I'd like to enable this facility for — a USB hard drive — does not have such a file in its corresponding directory, and that attempts to create it are rebuffed.

Is there perhaps a kernel module that needs to be loaded for this to work?  Do I need to build a custom kernel?  I'm running ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: [cross-posted on AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20266/power-persist-file-not-found-in-usb-device-sysfs-directory)

Comment: Can you give us the exact path you are trying to use for the file? Where do you echo "1"? Did you try to do that before/after the device was connected? Does this problem still exist?

Comment: I doubt the exact path will help, it depends on the vagaries of the USB tree of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

*As noted at the end of answer this is presumably already on. (Also when Q was posted.)*

Also note that the *cross post* was closed due to no answer – thus most appropriate to post here. And I imagine others can have use of the information.

---

The doc you linked [say](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/usb/persist.txt#100) (emphasize mine):

> […]
>   Note that the "USB-persist" feature will be applied only to those
>   devices for which it is enabled.  You can enable the feature by doing
>   (as root):
>
> echo 1 >/sys/bus/usb/devices/.../power/persist
>
> where the "..." should be filled in the with the device's ID.  Disable
>   the feature by writing 0 instead of 1. **For hubs the feature is
>   automatically and permanently enabled and the power/persist file
>   *doesn't even exist*, so you only have to worry about setting it for
>   devices where it really matters.**

In other words: (it seems like) you are trying to set it for a hub, which both is redundant – as it is always set, and not possible as file does not exist.

To see which paths actually has a `persist` file do:

```
$ ls -l /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/persist
```

To check status do:

```
$ tail /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/persist
```

If you use `lsusb` to identify device the correct path is

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/<BUS>-<DEVPATH>/power/persist
```

- `<BUS>` is from `lsusb`
- `<DEVPATH>` you can match against `Device` from `lsusb` by:

  ```
  $ tail <BUS>-*/devnum
  ```

Or check `dmesg`, etc. e.g.:

```
$ dmesg | grep -iA3 "new usb"
```

You can also verify by e.g.:

```
$ udevadm info -q all -p /sys/bus/usb/devices/<BUS>-<DEVPATH>
```

---

The policy for `persist` was changed to `on` as default by kernel 2.6.26-rc5.

Some ref's on the change to *enabled* by default:

- [[PATCH] usb: Make USB persist default configurable](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1303.2/01738.html)
- [[PATCH 6/6] USB: enable USB-PERSIST by default](http://marc.info/?l=linux-usb&m=120519727812208&w=2)
- [CONFIG_USB_PERSIST forced on](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=121276317104879&w=2)

The implementation:

- [USB: add USB-Persist facility](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=0458d5b4c9cc4ca0f62625d0144ddc4b4bc97a3c)